# Jquery- Hide/Show a div after a duration on page load

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I have a div which will display after some time .i.e on page load it will be invisible and after some duration it will be visible.

I tried this, but its not working for me.

```
setTimeout($(".startab").show(),4000);
$(".startab").delay(4000).show();
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xVChj/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to use a closure

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".startab").show()
}, 4000);
```

setTimeout takes a function as the first parameter and you were passing it an object

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVChj/3/)

Comment: thanks this works, Just curiosity why `$(".startab").delay(4000).show();` not works in this case

Comment: delay only works for animation chains. if you changed it to `$(".startab").delay(4000).show(1);` it becomes an animation

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` accepts a callback and a duration and should be called like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {$(".startab").show()},4000);
```