# Hide div for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i `hide one dive for 10 seconds or for 1 minute` using `jquery/jvascript` before site loads?

I know about `setTimeout` function, but it is used for hide dive after some time. but i want to hide div before sites load.

Comment: Think about it. Set it hidden to start in the CSS.

Comment: but after some time i want that dive back..

Comment: once my whole site get load, after that, that div can be seen..

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636362/show-div-after-2-seconds-of-page-load or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634783/jquery-hide-show-a-div-after-a-duration-on-page-load (There are more, did you even look?)

Comment: Or for "once my whole site get load, after that, that div can be seen.." [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23090493/1677912) is close, but you can just use the documentation for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Comment: *"but after some time i want that dive back..*" So use a setTimeout and show it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can hide initially using the css **[`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**
2. **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** for setting a delay
3. **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** for showing hidden element

**Snippet :**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hide').show()
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide" style="display:none">hidden</div>
```

Also you can use `visibility` in css

1. You can hide initially using the css **[`visibility:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)**
2. **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** for setting a delay
3. **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** for showing hidden element

**Snippet :**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hide').css('visibility','visible')
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide" style="visibility:hidden">hidden</div>
```

Comment: it working.. but there is problem.. text are not displaying which are in that div.. :(

Comment: @bluto : may be due to it's child elements inheriting display property from it's parent

Comment: actually in that div there is slider.. and that slider contains text and images

Comment: @bluto : check second method

Comment: @bluto : glad to help

Answer (score 4):

This code will show the div once the document is ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#initalHidden").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="initalHidden" style="display:none">
  <h1>Hidden until loaded</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make div display style to none
so it will be hidden before pageload

```
<div  id='target' style='display:none;'>This di will appear after 10 seconds  of page load</div>
<script>
   $(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ showTarget(); }, 10000);
   });
   function showTarget(){
       $("#target").show();
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it starts shown hide it,but better approach is to start hidden with CSS.

```
$(function() {
       var yourDiv = $("#yourDiv");
        yourDiv.hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#yourDiv").show();
        }, 10*1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose a div which id is **MyDiv** will have the effect you are looking for,

first i will set the css of the **MyDiv** hidden or display to none

```
#MyDiv
{
 display : none; 
}
```

or

```
#MyDiv
{
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

then it will remain hidden until the site loads and you change it through javascript.

in javascript after the desired time you just grab the element and make it visible

example in **jquery**:

```
$("#MyDiv").show();
```